# make[1]: ***No rule to make target 'zynq_xcomm_adv7511_deconfig'

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling

I've looked through a few of the posts relating to the error and can't see one which covers this specific circumstance. I'm trying to compile a kernel image as defined in these steps from a tutorial;

```
git clone https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/linux.git
Cloning into 'linux'...
remote: Counting objects: 2550298, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (466978/466978), done.
remote: Total 2550298 (delta 2118600), reused 2483072 (delta 2058083)
Receiving objects: 100% (2550298/2550298), 727.70 MiB | 353 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2118600/2118600), done.
Checking out files: 100% (38170/38170), done.
> cd linux
> git checkout xcomm_zynq
> # For AD-FMCOMMS2-EBZ use
> # git checkout xcomm_zynq 
> export ARCH=arm
> export CROSS_COMPILE=/path/to/your/arm/cross-compiler
> # e.g. export CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/arm-xilinxa9-linux-gnueabi-
> make zynq_xcomm_adv7511_defconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#
> make uImage LOADADDR=0x00008000
  ...
  OBJCOPY arch/arm/boot/uImage
  Kernel: arch/arm/boot/uImage is ready
```

I've followed all the steps up until I do the first make and get the error;

```
make[1]: ***No rule to make target 'zynq_xcomm_adv7511_deconfig'
```

I know very little about make and generally have used it blindly in the past. What does this error point towards? The Makefile should be fine as it's issued from Analog. The only difference is I'm using a different cross compiler - that being arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc instead. Would this cause a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo somewhere. It needs to be called zynq_xcomm_adv7511_defconfig